# Анализ рекламных ссылок на заданный сайт

Tags: seo

Можно ли как-то понять, какие именно сайты ссылаются на некий сайт?

Comment: Ломануть all-servs.com и посмотреть в логах рефереры? :-D

Comment: не ломать ничего не надо, просто есть какой то сервис или апи  например?. Нужно будет еще по другим сайтам возможно узнать

Comment: Попробуйте использовать Гугл для поиска https://www.google.se/search?q=free+inbound+links+too ++ https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/ ++ https://lxrmarketplace.com/seo-inbound-link-checker-tool.html

Comment: www.reference.com search.

Answer (score 5):

Для этой цели есть много сервисов (Ahrefs, Majestic, LinkPad). В настоящее время наиболее полный охват по найденным ссылкам предоставляет Ahrefs, но с недавнего времени они сделали свой сервис полностью платным. Также список ссылок можно посмотреть в панели вебмастера Google, Yandex и Bing (подходит, если вы являетесь администратором сайта). Некоторые ссылки на интересующий сайт можно найти и через прямой поиск в поисковых системах.

Comment: мне как раз нужно конкурента проанализировать

Comment: @heff тогда для этих целей самое лучшее, что есть ahrefs. в целом они индексируют 80-90% всех ссылок на сайт. это можно и так понять, если смотреть логи на своих серверах, нам ahrefs bot частый гость)) остальные находят меньше (что касается тех же google и yandex, то они выводят в открытом поиске малую часть ссылающихся страниц)

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте использовать **[Moz Open Site Explorer](https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/)**.